# An equation with distributions

Tags: analysis, distribution-theory

I am trying to solve the equation $\sin(x) T = 0$ where $T \in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ is a distribution.

I know that for such a distribution we have $\textrm{supp}(T) \subset \pi \mathbb{Z}$, but I don't know how to move on from here ...

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $\phi \in C^\infty_c(-1,1),\phi(0)=1$. For all $\psi\in C^\infty_c$
$$\langle T,\psi \rangle  = \langle T \sin,\frac{\psi-\sum_n \psi(\pi n)\phi(.+\pi n)}{\sin} \rangle
+ 
\sum_n \psi(\pi n)\langle T,\phi(.+\pi n)\rangle$$

$$ = \sum_n \langle T,\phi(.+\pi n)\rangle\langle \delta(.-\pi n),\psi\rangle$$
$$ = \langle \sum_n \langle T,\phi(.+\pi n)\rangle\delta(.-\pi n),\psi\rangle$$

Answer (score 2):

You have simply
$$
T(x) = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\lambda_k\delta(x-k\pi), \;\lambda_k\in\mathbb{R}
$$

N.B. : $T(x)$ doesn't contain derivatives of Dirac deltas, because $x^n\delta^{(m)}(x)\neq0\;\,\forall n \le m$ and $\sin(x) \sim x$.

Comment: I think there are some problems in your argument that no derivatives of $\delta$ can appear... although, I agree, your conclusion is correct. You'd want to note that the derivatives of $\delta$ are linearly independent (of course they are), and that $x\cdot \delta^{(n)}\not=0$ except for $n=0$...

Comment: @paulgarrett I expressed myself poorly : derivatives of Dirac deltas are killed by the higher powers of the Taylor expansion the sine function. That's now fixed.

Comment: well, yes, but I still think you're accidentally asserting the contrapositive (or something) of what you really intend. Thinking of the case $x\cdot u=0$ and being able to conclude that $u$ is a multiple of $\delta$ clarifies things for _me_, at least.

Comment: @paulgarrett I see what you meant; it should be okay now.

Comment: :) ............. :)